# Double overloading the istream and ostream operators in C++

Tags: c++, class, overloading, ostream, istream

I have a Fraction class that allows the input of a fraction in the form of c/d.
I can output and input fractions just fine, but when I modify them with my custom function, shown down below, it does nothing at all.

I have the following overloaded >> and << operators:

```
  ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Fraction &f)
{
    char x = '/';
    out << f.num;
    out << x;
    out << f.den;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &in, Fraction &r)
{
    //in >> r;
    int whole = 0, num, den = 1;
    char next;
    in >> num;
    next = in.peek();
    if(next == '+'){
        in.get();
        whole = num;
        in >> num;
        next = in.peek();
    }
    if(next == '/'){
        in.get();
        in >> den;
    }
    if(whole != 0){
        num += (whole * den);
    }
    if(den == 0){
        den = 1;
    }
    r.num = num;
    r.den = den;

    return in;
}
```

Furthermore, I have a function that makes two fractions so that they are with the same common denominator:

```
void setEqualDen(Fraction a, Fraction b){
    int tempa = a.den;
    int tempb = b.den;
    a.den *= tempb;
    b.den *= tempa;
    a.num *= tempb;
    b.num *= tempa;
}
```

I then try to output the result in the main as so:

```
setEqualDen(Fa, Fb);
    cout << "The fractions are " << Fa << " , " << Fb <<   
             endl;
```

This does not work. Is there a necessary step such as double overloading the << and >> operators in C++, or is my syntax simply missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*? If you mean the result is not what you expect, then it's because `setEqualDen` makes copies of its arguments instead of taking them by reference. If that's not the issue, then explain what you mean by *double overloading*, and post error messages, expected output etc.

Comment: Your input function fails with this text: "1+/25".

Comment: Rather than assuming the amount of white space, you should skip over it.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? If you mean the result is not what you expect, then it's because setEqualDen makes copies of its arguments instead of taking them by reference. If that's not the issue, then explain what you mean by double overloading, and post error messages, expected output etc. –  Praetorian///////////////////I wrote above. The problem is, nothing happens. It ignores the function completely.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `&` in the function definition, because you need to pass by reference since you're modifying your `Fractions.

```
void setEqualDen(Fraction &a, Fraction &b){
    int tempa = a.den;
    int tempb = b.den;
    a.den *= tempb;
    b.den *= tempa;
    a.num *= tempb;
    b.num *= tempa;
}
```

Comment: This will probably fix the OP's problem, but there's no reason for `setEqualDen` to be a member function since it's not accessing the instance it's being invoked on.

Comment: @Praetorian - yeah, that's a good point that's it's not necessary.  What's the preference here since the function is only valid for this particular class?  I would say make it a member, so that you can move the class around and not worry about recreating the function in another program.

Comment: @TriHard8 The error probably is that he's trying to invoke it without an instance of `Fraction`. It should be a free function in the same namespace as that of `Fraction`. Google "free functions improve encapsulation"

Comment: @Praetorian, agreed.  You should get credit for the answer.  I'll Google that for my own learning.

Comment: I'd set the question as answered by Praetorian, only it doesn't work yet. The stream functions are not allowing the other functions to work.

Comment: @JCoder - What do you mean?  You said your issue was with the `setEqualDen` not the stream functions.  You need to edit your original post and be clear what you're asking as well as add more code.  Without seeing your class code, it's hard to give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for input errors and skip whitespace.  I suggest using a temporary for containing the first digit, as it could be either the whole number or the numerator.  The differentiating needs to take place after the '/' is detected.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Fraction& f)
{
  int temp = 0;
  f.num = 0;
  f.den = 1;
  inp >> temp;  // Could be whole number or numerator.
  if (inp)
  {
    int whole = temp;
    int numerator = 0;
    inp >> numerator;
    if (!inp)
    {
      // Let's assume that the input failed because of the '/' symbol.
      numerator = temp;
      whole = 0;
      inp.clear();
    }
    else
    {
      inp.ignore(1000, '/'); // Skip over the '/'
    }
    int denominator = 1;
    inp >> denominator;
    if (denominator == 0) denominator = 1;
    numerator += whole * denominator;
    f.num = numerator;
    f.den = denominator;
  }
  return inp;
}
```